# How to insert multiple records with submitting only one time?

Tags: flask-admin

The structure of table: `id, article, tag` and, I defined a form with wtforms:

```
def scaffold_form(self):
    class MyForm(Forms):
        article = StringField('name')
        tags = Select2TagsField('tags') # tag1, tag2
    return MyForm
```

Here, I want insert multiple records (like [name, tag1], [name, tag2]) with submitting only one time, how can I implement it?